# wordpress admin panel not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I installed wordpress on the sub folder to cpanel and completed the work.

Now, i am moving the website to other cpanel on main domain. Everything is working fine on front end. But when i am trying to login to admin then i am getting error : ERROR 500 - INTERNAL SERVER ERROR

If i am trying to access the admin panel using wp-admin then it giving same error. but i tried with the wp-login.php and it shows login page but after adding correct login details it show error 500.

Thanks.

Comment: Try to delete `.htaccess` file. 500 Internal error occurs due to `.htaccess`  file issues.

Comment: i tried but it's not working.

Comment: You need to log in your log fils to see what the error is. It's impossible to help you till you actually find out WHAT the internal error is.

Comment: yeah, checked. But found nothing in error log.

Comment: FIXED: Permission issue on wp-admin folder. Thanks guys for your help.

Comment: please first you have to rename your plugin folder after that login when login successfully after that rename plugin folder.i think you have some plugin that get this error.

Answer (score 0):

Take care of few things:

1. Make sure URL's in DB tables are pointing to your domain.
2. ht-access is enabled.
3. Check setting in config again.

Comment: I checked everything and replaced htacces file too. But didn't get success. Thanks for your time

Comment: FIXED: Permission issue.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add: activate debug in wp-config.php, in 90% of the cases it tells you what's going on.

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```